# ASP.Net MVC- How to visible the login button in Individual Authentication mode?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, razor, registration

Why aren't the Login and Register buttons visible in ASP.net MVC anymore?

I've changed the authentication mode to Individual Authentication, and installed the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.Core` package. I ran the HomeController, but the buttons are still not showing up.

Is there something else that I missed? How can I make them visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a new project with Individual Authentication. If you're just changing it midway, the views won't be regenerated.